# Override library buildConfigFields in the application

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an application that uses an Android library as the primary source of code. Then I have multiple apps using that library; these apps will have the same code, but different configuration fields, such as endpoints and so.

To accomplish this, I thought I could have a `buildConfigField` in my library's `build.gradle` file, and then override that value in my app's `build.gradle` by using the same name, like this:

**build.gradle in library:**

```
buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", "\"http://arandomapibaseurl.com\""
```

**build.gradle in app:**

```
buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", "\"http://myrealapi.com\""
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, you have two separate `BuildConfig` classes, one for your library's package and one for your app's package. Your library knows nothing about the app's `BuildConfig`, and I'm not aware of a way for an app to override the `BuildConfig` from the library. You might need to explore other options (e.g., `<meta-data>` manifest elements pointing to XML resources, ordinary Java-based configuration, overriding assets).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't override build configs unfortunately.  You *can* override resource values specified with `resValue`.  The app can override the library, not the other way around.  You just need a context to pull them out, and you can do that at app launch to stick them into a java object that you can share as a singleton or whatever.

I have used this trick a lot in the past to let apps pull in a library and override its defaults.  You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code).

Comment: I ended up following that approach. I just created a config.xml per app that overrides the config resources in the library.

Comment: Great!  If it worked for you, please upvote and accept the answer.